# In a party with more than one monk, how do mantras work together?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

Monk Mantra descriptions say "*Only one Mantra can be active at a single time*".

But if we build a party with more than one monk:

- Is it possible get the effect of more Mantras?
- If two monks use the same Mantra, do their effects stack?
- If two monks use the same mantra with different strengths, does the strongest one always take precedence?
- Does the 3-second on-cast effect of the same Mantras stack?
- Do rune-effects of same-mantas stack?

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate.... this is asking about a specific skill and how it works when multiple Monks are playing together, not the pros and cons of having multiple Monks in a game.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mantras do not stack in a literal sense. Meaning two of the same Mantra *won't* provide double the results. However, two+ monks with two+ different Mantras active *will* stack as long as they are completley different Mantras. Alternativley, two+ monks with two+ of the same Mantra with different runes *will* stack. You can still gain the rune benefits from a Mantra, but you will not be doubling its effect.

You can see a conversation about it [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4796050760) and [here](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/2624878909).

Comment: Yes, that's a nice change since D2 and WoW, IIRC their aura-stacking rules did not account for auras improved by talents.

Answer (score 5):

You can have more than one different mantra effect active at one time if you're grouping with other Monks. The skill description is describing the Monks capability of providing a Mantra to a group, not their capability to gain mantra benefits.

The same Mantras do not stack, however their on-cast bonus (such as 3 second regen when casting Mantra of Healing) will stack. In addition as [Emerica pointed out](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69186/in-a-party-with-more-than-one-monk-how-do-mantras-work-together/69207#69207), if two monks use the same mantra with different rune effects, both rune effects get applied.

As for which mantra gets used if they differ in strength, I would assume the strongest mantra is the one used, however I will double-check later on.