# Does Inspiring Presence stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do Barbarian shouts stack for party members?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66648/do-barbarian-shouts-stack-for-party-members)

Does Inspiring Presence stack? so, if I use multiple shouts before the effect has finished; will I have increased healing for a while?

Comment: This question not a duplicate with that question is it? This is about Inspiring Presence's healing buff.

I take it from Sterno's answer that it doesn't stack though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not stack. Every time you shout simply resets the duration timer.