# Does Threatening Shout: Falter stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

As far as I understand, [Strongarm Bracers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/strongarm-bracers) stacks when multiple people pull enemies (it stacks additively in that if 2 people each add 30%, you get 60% damage instead of 1.3*1.3 = 69% damage). In [Patch 2.3](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/19814212/patch-230-ptr-patch-notes-8-6-2015), [Threatening Shout: Falter](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/active/threatening-shout) has been redesigned so to "Enemies take 25% increased damage from all sources for 6 seconds".

Does this stack with multiple party members, like Strongarm does? Does it stack additively in the same pool as Strongarm and other 'enemies take more damage' effects?

Comment: I believe shouts do not stack on friendly players or enemies. Only item affixes are able to stack. So I believe the answer to your questions is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Shouts of the same rune [do not stack.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/69360/204671) Still, shouts with different runes [do stack.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/78981/204671)

Comment: Couldn't this be closed as a duplicate of that other question then?

Comment: @Fabian sure, it seems appropriate imho to close as duplicate. unfortunately, I dont even have enough rep to flag it as duplicate. so, I suppose you could help out?

Comment: Done.__________